# Error processing condition in Micrometer (micrometerClock)

Tags: java, spring, atlas, micrometer

I'm trying to configure Micrometer with Atlas. I'm following the guides provided by Micrometer and Spring (I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1) and I don't understand what's failing.

I have the following configuration:

```
public class AtlasMeterConfiguration {

@Bean
MeterRegistry meterRegistry() {
    AtlasConfig atlasConfig = new AtlasConfig() {
        @Override
        public Duration step() {
            return Duration.ofSeconds(10);
        }

        @Override
        public String get(String k) {
            return null; // accept the rest of the defaults
        }
    };

    try(CompositeMeterRegistry compositeRegistry = new CompositeMeterRegistry();
        SimpleMeterRegistry oneSimpleMeter = new SimpleMeterRegistry()) {

        AtlasMeterRegistry atlasMeterRegistry = new AtlasMeterRegistry(atlasConfig, Clock.SYSTEM);
        compositeRegistry.add(oneSimpleMeter);
        compositeRegistry.add(atlasMeterRegistry);

        return atlasMeterRegistry;
    }
}
```

}

and I added this to one of my REST Controllers:

```
registry.timer("my.latency", "input").record(() -> {
        registry.get("my.latency").counter().increment();
        return registry.get("my.latency").counter();
    });
```

And the @Timed annotation, but all I get is the following error:

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.MetricsAutoConfiguration.micrometerClock
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.myapp.app.Application.main(Application.java:23)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.web.tomcat.TomcatMetricsConfiguration] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@66e94e22]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.248 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-07T10:06:34+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/564M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project apirest: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error processing condition on io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.MetricsAutoConfiguration.micrometerClock: Failed to introspect Class [io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.web.tomcat.TomcatMetricsConfiguration] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@66e94e22]: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedWebApplicationContext: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57528', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: `my.latency` is being registered as a timer and a counter. Give the different meters different names. Also all timers include counters, so the counter likely isn't even needed.  Also since `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` is missing, try adding the SpringBoot web starter as a dependency.

Comment: Do you mean `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>` ? That's already included in the project, of course! And thank you about the timer/counter information, I didn't know about that. It doesn't works yet ):

Comment: The problem was that I was importing the dependency of `micrometer-spring-legacy` because I read the guide to spring-boot 1.5.x instead of 2.0.x. That's why `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` was missing, in 2.0.x you don't have it. Thank you @checketts for your help :)

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer to help others that come across this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was importing the dependency of `micrometer-spring-legacy` because I read the guide for spring-boot 1.5.x instead of 2.0.x. That's why `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` was missing, in 2.0.x you don't have it.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean? In 2.0.x you don't have what?

Comment: mean remove the legacy dependency from pom

Answer (score 0):

Remove the legacy jar dependency from pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-spring-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```